# Group By and Count in a single sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables - users and login_reports.

users table have 4 columns - id, email, name, password, created_at, updated_at
login_reports table have 3 columns - id, user_id, created_at.

Every time user logins, an entry is created in login_reports.

Now I have to write a query to show login reports on admin dashoard.
The query should return rows of users having login count and last login.
Can someone help me with this.

```
SELECT users.id AS id, count(users.id) FROM users
INNER JOIN login_reports
ON users.id = login_reports.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

How do I get last login timestamp i.e. the last entry of that user in login_reports (created_at).

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I'm biased, but I prefer this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following query to solve this

```
SELECT users.id as id, count(login_reports.id) as login_count, login_reports.created_at as last_login FROM users LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM login_reports ORDER BY created_at DESC) login_reports ON users.id = login_reports.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```sql
select u.id, count(r.id), max(r.created_at) 
from user u 
left join login_reports r on r.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```

edit: thanks @tcadidot0

Comment: I am not getting last login timestamp. query throws an error

Comment: MySQL doesnt have `LAST()` ... but it have `MAX()` which I think is similar.